# Time & Space Complexity of Merge K Sorted List

Tags: java, time-complexity, heap, space-complexity

I wrote this solution to the problem mentioned, I am having trouble finding the complexities since I am less familiar with heaps, any suggestion/correction in my complexity analysis would help.

If `n` is the size of ArrayList
and `m` is the length of the longest linked list

According to me, the complexities should be as follows

Space Complexity: `O(nm)` (for heap)

Time Complexity: `O(nm)` (doubt this one)

```java
public class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeKLists(ArrayList<ListNode> a) {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>();
        for(ListNode node: a) {
            while(node != null) {
                minHeap.add(node.val);
                node = node.next;
            }
        }

        ListNode head = new ListNode(0);

        ListNode temp = head;
        while(minHeap.size() > 0) {
            ListNode newNode = new ListNode(minHeap.poll());
            temp.next = newNode;
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        return head.next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `k` sorted lists, and `n` total elements, then the time complexity of merging the lists is O(n * log(k)). The heap space required is O(k). Here's how it works.

First, create the heap and the head node of each list into it. So rather than a `PriorityQueue<Integer>`, you'd have a `PriorityQueue<ListNode>`. You'll have to write a custom comparator, of course, to sort on the value of the `ListNode`.

Now, when you poll the heap, you get the `ListNode` at the head of that list. If that node's `next` is not null, then push `next` back onto the heap. If the node's `next` is null, then you're at the end of that list and you don't push anything back onto the heap.

It looks something like:

```
ListNode head = new ListNode(0);
ListNode temp = head;

for each ListNode in a
  minHeap.add(a)

while minHeap is not empty
  node = minHeap.pop()
  if node.next is not null
    minHeap.push(node.next)
  temp.next = node;
  temp = node;

return head.next;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jim Mischel suggests, you want heap or priority queue of `ListNode`s, sorted by `ListNode.value`. In Java you can do this by supplying a custom `Comparator[ListNode]` that compares by value.

Here's some more detail on the complexity; I'll start with space complexity. You start by having all `n` lists added to the heap. This is the maximum size of the heap so the **space complexity is `O(n)`.** The size of the input lists doesn't affect the space used by the algorithm, you'd use the same `O(n)` elements in the heap/queue at the beginning, regardless of whether the max list length is `m=1` or `m=1e9`. So that's why it's not `O(m*n)`.

Now for time complexity. In the worst case, all `n` lists have the same maximum number of elements `m`, and we'll pop elements from them round-robin. Whenever you pop an element from a heap, or remove something from a priority queue, it takes `O(log(n))` operations. This is because the worst-case is you pop the top element, put the last element on the top, then have to sift it all the way down to the bottom of the heap. The heap is balanced so it has `O(log(n))` levels. Therefore this requires `O(log(n))` swaps and thus total operations.

We'll do `O(log(n))` operations for each element. There are `O(m*n)` elements in the worst case that every list has the same length `m`, so **the total time complexity is `O(m*n*log(n))`.**

For analyzing the complexities of heaps, here a couple of crucial facts:

- heap are balanced trees (but not search/sorted trees in general!). So push and pop operations that may sift all the way to the bottom or up to the top are `O(log(n))` operations, because that's the maximum depth of the tree
- accessing the minimum element (or max if it's a max heap) is `O(1)` because the structure of the tree guarantees the root node is the min/max, and you can access a specific element in `O(1)`
- counter-intuitively, *creating* a heap from `n` elements is an `O(n)` operation. One would expect `n` push operations of `O(log(n))` each would be `O(n*log(n))`. This is true in the general case. But when building a heap, you can build it from the bottom up such that half of your elements won't move, a quarter of your elements can sift down exactly one level, an eighth can be sifted down 2 levels, etc. When you evaluate that series, you find that the total operations done is only `O(n)`. This is known as "heapifying"